# Difflib error when applying onto two columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, difflib

I have DataFrame that look like this:

```
Cities        Cities_Dict
"San Francisco" ["San Francisco", "New York", "Boston"]
"Los Angeles"   ["Los Angeles"]
"berlin"        ["Munich", "Berlin"]
"Dubai"         ["Dubai"]
```

I want to create new column that compares city from firest column to the list of cities from secon column and finds the one that is the closest match.
I use `difflib` for that:

```
df["new_col"]=difflib.get_close_matches(df["Cities"],df["Cities_Dict"])
```

However I get error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with lambda function and `axis=1` for processing by rows:

```
import difflib, ast

#if necessary convert values to lists
#df['Cities_Dict'] = df['Cities_Dict'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

f = lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x["Cities"],x["Cities_Dict"])
df["new_col"] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
print (df)
          Cities                        Cities_Dict          new_col
0  San Francisco  [San Francisco, New York, Boston]  [San Francisco]
1    Los Angeles                      [Los Angeles]    [Los Angeles]
2         berlin                   [Munich, Berlin]         [Berlin]
3          Dubai                            [Dubai]          [Dubai]
```

EDIT:

For first value with empty string for empty list use:

```
f = lambda x: next(iter(difflib.get_close_matches(x["Cities"],x["Cities_Dict"])), '')
df["new_col"] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
print (df)
          Cities                        Cities_Dict        new_col
0  San Francisco  [San Francisco, New York, Boston]  San Francisco
1    Los Angeles                      [Los Angeles]    Los Angeles
2         berlin                   [Munich, Berlin]         Berlin
3          Dubai                            [Dubai]          Dubai
```

EDIT1: If possible problematic data is possible use `try-except`:

```
def f(x):
    try:
        return difflib.get_close_matches(x["Cities"],x["Cities_Dict"])[0]
    except:
        return ''

df["new_col"] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
print (df)
        Cities                        Cities_Dict new_col
0          NaN  [San Francisco, New York, Boston]        
1  Los Angeles                               [10]        
2       berlin                   [Munich, Berlin]  Berlin
3        Dubai                            [Dubai]   Dubai
```

Comment: Is it possible to get result not as a list but as a string?

Comment: @AlexT - answer was edited - always return first value of list or empty string

Comment: I found out that some values in Cities_Dict ended up floats or ints, is it possible to use try, except in the lambda function that would skip those rows and produce empty string for them?

Comment: And second question why do you use next and iter?

Comment: @AlexT - for first, answer was edited. For second this is a trick - problem here is use selecting by `[0]` for first value of list, because if empty list it return error - like `L = ['Dubai']` and `L[0]` working, but if `L = []` then `L[0]` failed. And for prevent failed is used `next` with `iter` - it return first value of list, if exist (if not empty list) else default value, here empty string